# Macro para abrir, empilhar e salvar diversos arquivos .csv sequenciais no SPSS

Tags: loop, macro, spss

Como programar uma macro que:

1. Importe apenas algumas colunas (por exemplo: `ano`, `mes`, `id`, `valor` e `motivo` ) de  arquivos .csv sequenciais para o SPSS. Esses arquivos teriam nomes do tipo: `DADOS_JAN_2010`,  `DADOS_FEV_2010`, [...], até `DADOS_DEZ_2019`.
2. Altere os comprimentos das variaveis string `id` para `(a11)`, `motivo` para `(a32)`, quando for o caso (necessário para compatibilizar os arquivos dos diferentes anos).
3. Empilhe todos esses dados num novo conjunto de dados/tabela com nome do tipo: `DADOS_2010_2019`.

Caso seja útil, um exemplo dos dados:

```
| ANO  | MÊS | ID          | VALOR | MOTIVO |
|------|-----|-------------|-------|--------|
| 2010 | 1   | 12345678910 | 1100  | promo  |
| 2010 | 1   | 12345678911 | 200   | faltas |
| 2010 | 1   | 12345678912 | 1450  | meta   |
| 2010 | 1   | 12345678913 | 400   | faltas |
| 2010 | 1   | 12345678914 | 1800  | meta   |
| 2010 | 1   | 12345678915 | 600   | padrao |
| 2010 | 1   | 12345678916 | 700   | padrao |
| 2010 | 1   | 12345678917 | 800   | meta   |
| 2010 | 1   | 12345678918 | 900   | meta   |
| 2010 | 1   | 12345678919 | 1000  | promo  |
| 2010 | 1   | 12345678920 | 800   | padrao |
```

Por enquanto, estou abrindo, empilhando e salvando os arquivos de dois em dois. Mas isso é repetitivo e pouco eficiente. Além disso, se no futuro for necessário incluir mais variáveis, será preciso refazer todo o código. Por isso, acredito que uma macro seria a maneira mais inteligente para realizar essa tarefa.

Um exemplo de parte do meu código até agora:

```
GET DATA  /TYPE=TXT
  /FILE="C:\Users\luizz\DADOS\DADOS_JAN_2010.csv"
  /ENCODING='Locale'
  /DELCASE=LINE
  /DELIMITERS=";"
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED
  /FIRSTCASE=2
  /IMPORTCASE=ALL
  /VARIABLES=
  ANO F4.0
  MES F1.0
  ID A11
  VALOR F4.0
  MOTIVO A8.
CACHE.
EXECUTE.
DATASET NAME JAN_2010 WINDOW=FRONT.

ALTER TYPE MOTIVO (a32).

GET DATA  /TYPE=TXT
  /FILE="C:\Users\luizz\DADOS\DADOS_FEV_2010.csv"
  /ENCODING='Locale'
  /DELCASE=LINE
  /DELIMITERS=";"
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED
  /FIRSTCASE=2
  /IMPORTCASE=ALL
  /VARIABLES=
  ANO F4.0
  MES F1.0
  ID A11
  VALOR F4.0
  MOTIVO A8.
CACHE.
EXECUTE.
DATASET NAME FEV_2010 WINDOW=FRONT.

DATASET ACTIVATE FEV_2010.
ALTER TYPE MOTIVO (a32).

DATASET ACTIVATE JAN_2010.
ADD FILES /FILE=*
  /FILE='FEV_2010'.
EXECUTE.

SAVE OUTFILE='C:\Users\luizz\DADOS\DADOS_JAN_FEV_2010.sav'
  /COMPRESSED.
```

Alguém saberia como programar uma macro para isso no SPSS?

Obrigado,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, eu fiz a mesma pergunta no stackoverflow em inglês e um usuário de lá @eli-k, soube responder. O link para a resposta está [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64608413/open-recode-and-stack-several-csv-files/64634366). E os créditos do código são do usuário citado.

Eu tenho amigos que já passaram por dificuldades semelhantes na importação de dados sequencias .csv para o SPSS. Várias bases de dados do governo brasileiro são disponibilizadas segmentadas dessa maneira. Os dados de internações hospitalares do DataSus, por exemplo, têm o exato formato descrito aqui. Os dados de mercado de trabalho da RAIS são disponibilizados por UF e por ano, então a lógica é mais ou menos a mesma. Esses dados são muito grandes para serem trabalhados no R, por isso, pode ser útil abri-los no SPSS. Por essas razões, resolvi traduzir e compartilhar a resposta a essa pergunta do stackoverflow em inglês aqui:

> Considerando que os parâmetros para todos os arquivos são iguais ao da sua pergunta, você pode utilizar a seguinte macro:

```
define !getfiles ()
!do !yr=2010 !to 2019
!do !mn !in("JAN FEV MAR ABR MAI JUN JUL AGO SET OUT NOV DEZ")
GET DATA 
  /TYPE=TXT /FILE=!concat('"C:\Users\luizz\DADOS\DADOS_', !mn, '_', !yr, '.csv"')
  /ENCODING='Locale'   /DELCASE=LINE   /DELIMITERS=";"   /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED
  /FIRSTCASE=2   /IMPORTCASE=ALL   /VARIABLES= 
  YEAR F4.0
  MONTH F1.0
  ID A11
  VALUE F4.0
  MOTIVE A8.
CACHE.
EXECUTE.
ALTER TYPE id (a11) MOTIVE (a32).
dataset name tmp.
dataset activate gen.
add files /file=* /file=tmp.
exe.
!doend !doend
!enddefine.
```

> A macro foi definida para ler cada um dos arquivos e adicioná-los a um arquivo principal. Antes de chamarmos a macro, precisamos criar o arquivo principal:

```
data list list/YEAR (F4)  MONTH (F1) ID (A11) VALUE (F4) MOTIVE (A8).
begin data
end data.
exe.
dataset name gen.
* Agora chamamos a macro
!getfiles .
* Agora que os dados estão empilhados, podemos salvá-los
SAVE OUTFILE='C:\Users\luizz\DADOS\DATA_2010_2019.sav'  /COMPRESSED.
```